# php filesize() always returns same value

Tags: php, image, gd

I am trying to upload an image via PHP. On upload, it should become resized that its' dimensions are as big as I defined it in my config[]-array and that its' filesize is also smaller or equal to the predefined value in my config[]-array. But somehow, the method getFileSize() always returns the same size, even after resizing the image.

Here's my code. Explanation follows.

```
$tries = 0;
while ( $image->getFileSize() > $config['image_max_file_size'] && $tries < 10 ) {
    $factor = 1 - (0.1 * $tries);

    echo $image->getFileSize().PHP_EOL;
    if ( !$image->resize($config['image_max_width'], $config['image_max_height'], $factor) ) {
            return false;
    }

    $tries++;
}
```

**$image** is an object of the type Picture, which is just a wrapper-class for all kind of functions I need related to modifying pictures.

**$config** is my configuration-array which includes all kind of predefined values.

**$tries** holds the number of tries that are allowed. The program is allowed to resize the image no more than 10 times.

**getFileSize()** returns the image-filesize via return filesize(*path*)

**resize(maxWidth,maxHeight,factor)** resizes the image to the size mentioned in the parameters. After it resized the picture, it saves the result to the same *path*, the filesize is read from.

I'll just post the resize() and getFileSize() method, since it may interest you:

```
function resize($neededwidth, $neededheight, $factor) {

    $oldwidth = $this->getWidth($this->file_path);
    $oldheight = $this->getHeight($this->file_path);
    $neededwidth = $neededwidth * $factor;
    $neededheight = $neededheight * $factor;
    $fext = $this->getInnerExtension();

    $img = null;
    if ($fext == ".jpeg" ) {
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->file_path);
    } elseif ($fext == ".png") {
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($this->file_path);
    } elseif ($fext == ".gif") {
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($this->file_path);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $newwidth = 0;
    $newheight = 0;
    if ($oldwidth > $oldheight && $oldwidth > $neededwidth) { // Landscape Picture
        $newwidth = $neededwidth;
        $newheight = ($oldheight / $oldwidth) * $newwidth;      
    } elseif ($oldwidth < $oldheight && $oldheight > $neededheight) { // Portrait Picture
        $newheight = $neededheight;
        $newwidth = ($oldwidth / $oldheight) * $newheight;
    }

    $finalimg = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($finalimg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $oldwidth, $oldheight);

    if ($fext == ".jpeg" ) {
        if ( !imagejpeg($finalimg, $this->file_path, 100) ) return false;
    } elseif ($fext == ".png") {
        if ( !imagepng($finalimg, $this->file_path, 9) ) return false;
    } elseif ($fext == ".gif") {
        if ( !imagegif($finalimg, $this->file_path) ) return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    imagedestroy($img);
    return true;
}
```

getFileSize()

```
function getFileSize() {

        return filesize($this->file_path);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `clearstatcache()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: Thanks :P Actually you were first, but can't accept this answer :S

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

```
function getFileSize() {
    clearstatcache();
    return filesize($this->file_path);
}
```